# In IntelliJ is there any package/class browser like Eclipse's Java Browsing perspective?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Being a long-time Eclipse power user, I'm totally addicted to the Smalltalk-style package and class browser it presents in the [Java Browsing perspective](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-Browsing.htm). Is there anything similar for IntelliJ?

[image]

Note: I'm not looking for IntelliJ's Project window; that's more like Eclipse's Package Explorer or Project Explorer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can achieve something similar with opening these tool windows:

- Structure (View > Tool Windows > Structure);
- Type Hierarchy (Navigate > Type Hierarchy)
- Project, but choose its "Packages" view
- Favorites, and add the whole project as a favorite (either with drag and drop or via right-clicking it)

Then you can rearange the windows to match your preference - see attached screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to duplicate the Structure tool window so I can see both Packages view and Project Files view at the same time?

Comment: I don't think so. The closest thing you can achieve is to right click on a module and choose "Add to Favorites". Then in Favorites you will have the project files, while in Project you will have your packages. I will update the answer above with screenshot later.

Comment: Screenshot updated, together with the explanation above

Comment: Although I wish I could stack tool windows 3-high along one side like I can stack Views in Eclipse, this is workable as long as I'm on a large monitor. But it doesn't leave enough editor space on a laptop screen :-(

Answer (score 1):

For flattened package view like Eclipse, you can configure intellij like

[image]